# Como usar o str_replace para substituir várias palavras?

Tags: php

Estou exibindo uma data de uma postagem que estou puxando do instagram, mas ela é exibida assim:

> Thu, 26 Sep 2019 13:47:05 GMT

Ele ta resultando em nomes em inglês de cada dia da semana, mas eu quero remover ele e tirar o nome do mês 'Sep' e deixar apenas o número do mês junto com a data e remover a palavra GMT, ficaria igual:

> 26/09/2019 h:13:47:05

O que eu tentei foi:

```html
<?php
$instaResult = simplexml_load_file('https://rss.app/feeds/wUySUmu0Kiy1c3uL.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA) or die("error");
$instagram_photos = $instaResult->channel->item[0]->enclosure['url'];
//data da publicacao
$instagram_date = $instaResult->channel->item[0]->pubDate;

//Trocando nome do mes de ingles para portugues
echo str_replace("Thu", "Quinta", $instagram_date);


// descricao do instagram
$instagram_description = htmlentities((string)$instaResult[0]->channel->item[0]->description);
echo "</br>";
$result = trim(strip_tags(str_replace(array("<![CDATA[","]]>"),array("",""),(string)$instaResult[0]->channel->item[0]->description)));
 echo $result;

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1800'; url='index.php'>"; //atualiza a cada 30 minutos
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css?version=700'>";
echo "<div class='fundo'>";
echo "</div>";

// DEFINE O FUSO HORARIO COMO O HORARIO DE BRASILIA
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
// CRIA UMA VARIAVEL E ARMAZENA A HORA ATUAL DO FUSO-HORÀRIO DEFINIDO (BRASÍLIA)
$hour = (int)date('G');
if ($hour >= 0 && $hour < 10)
{
 // 00:00 até 09:59
 $resp = "<img class='logo' src='logo.jpg' alt=''/>";
}
else
{
 // 10:00 até 23:59
 $resp = "<img class='img-responsive' src='{$instagram_photos}'/>";
}

echo $resp;
?>
```

Se puderem me ajudar desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o constructor da classe ['DateTime'](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.construct.php) para obter um objeto do tipo 'DateTime' a partir de uma string em conformidade ao formato [UTC](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iso:std:iso:8601:-1:ed-1:v1:en) e método ['DateTime::format'](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php) para formatar a data a seu gosto.

*Tabela para os caracteres para string de formatação para função DateTime::format'*
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

```
<?php

   $instaResult = simplexml_load_file('https://rss.app/feeds/wUySUmu0Kiy1c3uL.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA) or die("error");

   $instagram_date = new DateTime($instaResult->channel->item[0]->pubDate);

   echo $instagram_date->format('d/m/Y \h:H:i:s');

// Ou numa abordagem mais objetiva que produz o mesmo resultado
// echo (new DateTime($instaResult->channel->item[0]->pubDate))->format('d/m/Y \h:H:i:s');

?>
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FreshQuerulousBaitware)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Me ajudou muito!